# What is a good temporary install directory for Debian packages?

Tags: debian, node.js

I'm writing the debian packaging for a Meteor application.  The `meteor build` command will create a "bundle" that requires `npm install` to be run on it (to resolve its node.js dependencies); then we'll be ready to package the files.

Where to create the bundle?

I decided to create it in a subdirectory of debian/tmp, like this (in the rules file):

```
override_dh_auto_build:
    cd bigbluebutton-html5; meteor build --directory ../debian/tmp/bigbluebutton-html5
    cd debian/tmp/bigbluebutton-html5/bundle/programs/server; npm install
```

But debian/tmp gets deleted at the start of the binary phase, by `dh_prep`.  I can fix this by overriding `dh_prep`, like this:

```
# This is here to prevent removal of debian/tmp during the install step.
override_dh_prep:
```

But this seems counter-intuitive.

Can anybody suggest a better place to stage the "bundle"?  Or a better way to package Meteor projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done in a `build` directory under the project’s top level, or in `debian/build`. Whichever one you choose, make sure to add it to `debian/clean`, with a trailing slash, so it gets removed at the start of the build.

Using `debian/tmp` would cause issues beyond the `dh_prep` problem you’ve run into; for example, `dh_missing` expects everything in `debian/tmp` to be installed somewhere in the resulting packages.

There has been some discussion in the Debian development community around this in the last few months, see [this thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2020/05/msg00011.html) which recently attempted to suggest a more extensive proposal.